# Attempting to solve jquery async issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, mailgun

I am pretty new to javascript, and I am trying to work with mailgun's email validation feature and I am trying to get the validation to work (by ensuring the email data is intact prior to submission of a form.

https://github.com/mailgun/validator-demo

However I found that the function validation_success is always called asynchronously, resulting in the sequence as below:

```
checks start!
Feedback:390 checks complete! ErrorEmail=2
Feedback:347 execution begin
Feedback:404 validation begin! ErrorEmail=2
Feedback:419 validation complete! ErrorEmail=2
```

I want the sequence to be the following instead:

```
checks start!
validation begin! ErrorEmail=2        //this will update the ErrorEmail var.
validation complete! ErrorEmail=2
checks complete! ErrorEmail=2
execution begin
```

I have searched and tried all the techniques (async false/deferred/callbacks), but I can't seem to figure out what might have went wrong.

My code is as below:

```
        var ErrorEmail = -1;
        $(function () {

            $('#User_Email').mailgun_validator({
                api_key: 'x',
                in_progress: validation_in_progress, // called when request is made to validator
                success: validation_success,         // called when validator has returned
                error: validation_error,           // called when an error reaching the validator has occured
            });

            $("#FeedbackForm").submit(function (event) {
                if($("#User_Email").val())
                {
                    check().done(function(){
                        console.log('execution begin');
                            if (ErrorEmail == 2) {
                            if (confirm('Are you sure this is the email you want to use?')) {
                                $(form).submit();
                            }
                        }
                        else if (ErrorEmail == 0)
                        {
                            $(form).submit();
                        }
                    });

                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('no email');
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        });

        function check(callback) {
            var dfrd1 = $.Deferred();
            console.log('checks start!');
            dfrd1.resolve(
                $('#User_Email').mailgun_validator({
                    api_key: 'x',
                    in_progress: validation_in_progress, // called when request is made to validator
                    success: validation_success,         // called when validator has returned
                    error: validation_error,           // called when an error reaching the validator has occured
                }).done()
            );

            console.log('checks complete! ErrorEmail='+ErrorEmail);
            return dfrd1.done().promise();
        }

        // while the lookup is performing
        function validation_in_progress() {
            $('#status').html("<img src=@Url.Content(@"~/Assets/img/loading.gif") height='16'/>");
        }

        // if email successfully validated
        function validation_success(data) {
            //var dfrd1 = $.Deferred();
            //dfrd1.resolve(data);

            console.log('validation begin! ErrorEmail=' + ErrorEmail);
            $('#status').html(get_suggestion_str(data['is_valid'], data['did_you_mean']));

            if (data['is_valid'] && !data['did_you_mean']) {
                ErrorEmail = 0;
            }
            else if (data['is_valid'] && data['did_you_mean']) {
                ErrorEmail = 2;
            }
            else
                ErrorEmail = 1;
            console.log('validation complete! ErrorEmail=' + ErrorEmail);

            //return dfrd1.promise();
        }

        // if email is invalid
        function validation_error(error_message) {
            $('#status').html(error_message);
        }

        // suggest a valid email
        function get_suggestion_str(is_valid, alternate) {
            if (is_valid) {
                ErrorEmail = 0;
                var result = '<span class="success">Address is valid.</span>';
                if (alternate) {
                    result += '<span class="warning"> (Though did you mean <em>' + alternate + '</em>?)</span>';
                    ErrorEmail = 2;
                }
                return result
            } else if (alternate) {
                ErrorEmail = 1;
                return '<span class="warning">Did you mean <em>' + alternate + '</em>?</span>';
            } else {
                ErrorEmail = 1;
                return '<span class="error">Email address is invalid. Please try another.</span>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Hey @Amy, I want the sequence to be as below instead (to ensure the email is verified first before executing the form):

checks start!
validation begin! ErrorEmail=2
validation complete! ErrorEmail=2
checks complete! ErrorEmail=2
execution begin

Comment: If you are wanting things to run in order then you need to put things in the callback functions - eg your checks complete should go in the done of the mailgun validator

Comment: @Pete do you mind giving an example? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at your check.done function above

Comment: @Pete do you mean putting console.log('checks complete! ErrorEmail='+ErrorEmail) within  $('#User_Email').mailgun_validator({}).done()?

Comment: putting whatever you need to do after that in there

Answer (score 0):

`check()` function already has a `deferred` object (`$('#User_Email').mailgun_validator`) the only thing to do is `.pipe` result of that function and call `resolve` function of `dfrdl` and in the end **return dfrdl ONLY** like below:

```
function check(callback) {
    var dfrd1 = $.Deferred();
    console.log('checks start!');
    $('#User_Email').mailgun_validator({
            api_key: 'x',
            in_progress: validation_in_progress, // called when request is made to validator
            success: validation_success,         // called when validator has returned
            error: validation_error,           // called when an error reaching the validator has occured
        }).pipe(function(res){
            dfrd1.resolve(res);
        })

    console.log('checks complete! ErrorEmail='+ErrorEmail);
    return dfrd1;
}
```